# Can't access Dev org due to Privacy Error

Tags: login

I have been using a Dev org for a long time.  I enabled the My Site feature about 6 months ago, so whenever I login, I get redirected to my URL (myname-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com).  This has been working fine for months.  Yesterday it stopped working.  When I try to access the site, either through the login.salesforce.com site or directly on my custom URL, I get a "Connection is not private" error message.  In Chrome I usually can click Advanced on this error page and proceed.  But when I click advanced, it says the following: You cannot visit myname-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.

This org has all of my Trailhead and training work.  Any ideas?  Any way to disable my site via an API call or something?  Really need this org back.

Comment: You enabled the "My Domain" feature, not sites. Once enabled, it cannot be disabled. The issue you're having is likely because of something else. You can always add the domain to your trusted sites list, but it doesn't sound as though that's what is causing your issue.